# Parse JSON-like data in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am getting a return from an API call through NodeJS as data similar to JSON.

I am getting the reply as:

```
{ abc: 10,
  qwe: 5 }
```

If the above was as shown below:

```
{ "abc": 10,
  "qwe": 5 }
```

I could have used JSON.parse function, but the former can't be used with JSON.parse.

Is there any way I can get the value of `qwe` from that response?

Comment: Do you need to parse the data, or is it actually already in json format? What happens when you try to log `data.qwe` from your request for example? It may help us if you show a little more code surrounding the result that gives you the format in question.

Comment: It is in the former format (one without the quotes). So, I cannot parse it with JSON.parse neither data.qwe

Comment: How is source generated? Should fix it there

Comment: I cannot do that, I am using some one else' api.

Comment: is the reply a string? how do you store that reply?

Comment: We need more info. Show all the code that makes a request and how you are handling the response. For example, in XMLHttpRequest, it is possible to specify a response type such as `request.responseType = 'json';` In addition, there are a variety of error messages you could be generating that would give us more insight into developing a solution. When you tried logging the result of `data.qwe` what error message did you get?

Comment: @asterisk I added another option to my answer, where you handle the non-json non-object string from the server by parsing manually through it and turning it into JSON format. check it out.

Comment: @asterisk it appears that you already have an object. Can you console.log (response.keys()) where response is the variable you show above ? This should give you both abc and qwe. See [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Option 1: It's already an object.***

The item you're showing is already an object. It doesn't need parsing through. JSON.parse() is meant to go through a string and turn it into an object. just work with the object itself.

Example:

```
const object = {abc:10, qwe:5};

console.log(object.abc);       // > 10
console.log(object["qwe"]);    // > 5
```

***Option 2: It is a non-JSON string.***

In this case maybe you can predict the pattern and manually turn into a JSON format that you can parse later?

something like:

```
const nonJson = "{abc: 10, qwe: 5 }";
let jsoned = nonJson.replace(/(:\s+)/g, "\":\"");
jsoned = jsoned.replace(/(,\s+)/g, "\",\"");
jsoned = jsoned.replace(/({\s*)/, "{\"");
jsoned = jsoned.replace(/(\s+})/, "\"}");

const object = JSON.parse(jsoned);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do this, it's a bit ugly though, you can do:

```
var unquotedJson = '{ abc: 10, qwe: 5 }';

var object = eval('('+ unquotedJson +')');
```

NB: eval is only to be used with a trusted source, since it will execute JavaScript code.

I should also mention that unquoted JSON is not really JSON!

Comment: Should also note that it doesn't come without serious security concerns also

Comment: You're right, eval is dangerous, only to be used with a trusted source.